# unmet dependencies problem ros indigo ubuntu 32 bits trusty

Tags: ros, ubuntu, ros-indigo, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI! How are you doing?

I'm following the instructions( http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu ) to install ROS Indigo in my 32bit PC, with Ubuntu:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

and finally i'm getting this error:

```
jrr10@jrr10:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-indigo-desktop-full : Depends: ros-indigo-desktop but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-indigo-perception but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-indigo-simulators but it is not going to be installed
 unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I've read a lot of posts and questions but i couldn't achieve my goal.

I would appreciate if you could help me out to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Juan.-

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245347/unmet-dependencies-problem-ros-indigo-ubuntu-32-bits-trusty/) by [jrr10](https://answers.ros.org/users/28194/jrr10/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-10-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jrr10](https://answers.ros.org/users/28194/jrr10/) on 2016-10-09**:
Now, im just getting this error:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ros-indigo-desktop-full : Depends: ros-indigo-desktop but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-indigo-perception but it is not going to be installed
Depend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just solved my problem! I downgraded my ubuntu version to 14.04.2 and just worked perfectly!

---

Originally posted by [jrr10](https://answers.ros.org/users/28194/jrr10/) with karma: 16 on 2016-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0